# constrOptim: Minimise a function subject to linear inequality constraints using an adaptive barrier algorithm

Tags: r, optimization, constraints, nonlinear-optimization

I'm trying to minimize a loss function using `constrOptim`. My constraint is the Feller Condition of the form 2*θ*κ ≥ σ², which corresponds to `2*x1*x2 ≥ x4^2` e.g. `x4^2- 2*x1*x2` in my code. My starting values are `x0 <- c(0.05, -0.85, 3.00, 0.32)` and the loss function is of the form 1/N * sum(w_i * (market_price - model_price)^2) and simply called `loss_function`. `model_price`contains four unknown parameters which I have to calibrate using the optimization but I don't quite understand how to set up the constraint matrix `ui` and constraint vector `ci` from `constrOptim`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation `constrOptim` accepts only **linear** inequality constraints, your constraints are non-linear, so this won't work. Here is one way to solve this using the `NlcOptim` package.

```
library(NlcOptim)

w_i=runif(4)
model_price=rnorm(4)
x0=c(0.05,-0.85,3.00,0.32)

objfun=function(x){
  sum(w_i*(x-model_price)^2)/length(x)
}

confun=function(x){
  f=NULL
  f=rbind(f,x[4]^2-2*x[1]*x[2])
  list(ceq=NULL,c=f)
}

solnl(x0,objfun=objfun,confun=confun)
```

Comment: When I run this with a bigger dataset I get "error in A(indxact, , drop = F) : could not find function "A". Do I need to specifiy this?

Comment: @rubwoer This is hard to answer without seeing exactly what is going on. You do not need to specify A, which is optional and used for linear inequality constraints.

Comment: my final goal is to calibrate an option pricing model, the Heston SV model. I use `callHestoncf` from `NMOF` like this: `for (i in 1:1374){
    y[i] <- callHestoncf(S = S[i], X = K[i], tau = tau[i], r = r[i], q = q[i], v0 = 0.04,
                         vT = x[1], rho = x[2], k = x[3], sigma = x[4], implVol = FALSE)` to generate model prices dependent on the four unknowns with a for loop . Then I substract that in the objective function from my market prices as stated above. The whole function is too big to write as a comment sorry but I hope you get the picture

Comment: I also have upper and lower bounds for the estimates: `lb <- c(0.01, -1, 1, 0.01)` & `ub <- c(1, -0.2, 10, 1)`

Comment: @rubwoer Unfortunately I cannot figure out the issue from your description. It would be better to post a new question with a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: I posted a new question. You can find it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65577935/constroptim-minimise-a-loss-function-to-calibrate-option-model-parameters-using
Thanks in advance!